# remove object from stage and array when leaving stage

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

To an extent this is working, but it's only removing the tempBullet object if its y position starts at < 200, not if it reaches that point after being spawned somewhere further down the stage:

```
        if(firing && bulletTimeOut == 0)
        {
            var tempBullet = new Bullet();
            bullets.push(tempBullet);
            tempBullet.x = x;
            tempBullet.y = y-10;
            stage.addChild(tempBullet);
            trace(bullets.length);
            if(tempBullet.y < 200)
            {
                bullets.splice(tempBullet, 1);
                stage.removeChild(tempBullet);
            }
            bulletTimeOut = 5;
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this code happening in a loop?

I think that rather than just checking the position of `tempBullet` you intended to loop through the whole bullets array to remove any bullets that have gone past 200px.

```
if(firing && bulletTimeOut == 0)
{
    var tempBullet = new Bullet();
    bullets.push(tempBullet);
    tempBullet.x = x;
    tempBullet.y = y-10;
    stage.addChild(tempBullet);
    trace(bullets.length);
    bulletTimeOut = 5;
}
// test bullet positions whether firing or not
for each (b:Bullet in bullets) {
    if(b.y < 200)
    {
        bullets.splice(b, 1);
        stage.removeChild(b);
    }
}
```